# Coded UI data driven Load test issue

Tags: performance, load-testing, coded-ui-tests

I have Web Performance Test created in Coded UI 2013, this test uses a csv file for providing the Form Post-parameters value. Now, from this performance test I have created a Load Test with number of users as '2' and number of iterations as '4', but when I run this Load Test I found that it is always picking up only First entry/row from the csv file, while I want it to pick different row for each user/iteration in a sequential way. I verified the properties of csv file and it's 'Access Method' value is 'Sequential'. I have tried with different 'Test mix Type' models too, but still same result.

I want to parametrize this load test so that each user uses a new row from csv file?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got solution for the same, actually I was looking the VSTS Performance tests in wrong way. Unlike other performance/load testing tools (like JMeter) VSTS is picking up values from csv file per Iteration base not per User base. So, in VSTS if there is only 1 iteration while number of users as 4, 10 etc. (any number), then it will always pick only 1st entry from csv file. Whereas if we increase number of iteration then VSTS starts picking up values from csv file in sequential way. I feel this a bit weird behavior as compared to other tools I have worked on, but may be this is the way VSTS works.